# Post to Linkedin Groups API 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, json, rest, linkedin-api

I'm getting a 400 Bad Request Posting my JSON to the Groups API. I'm assuming it's because my JSON for the post is formatted incorrectly. Wondering if anyone has posted successfully to the groups API and could provide some assistance. The XML example indicates  surrounding the content. Do I need to include post?

Here's my JSON

```
{\"title\":\"Testing out the LinkedIn Share API with JSON\",\"content\":{\"title\":\"News Article\",\"submitted-url\":\"http%3a%2f%2fmysite.com%2fcontent.aspx%3fpage_id%3d5%26club_id%3d652588%26item_id%3d300\",\"description\":\"hey this is a description\"}}
```

Here's the object I'm using to build it:

```
var post = new {
title = "Testing out the LinkedIn Share API with JSON",
content = new Dictionary<string, string>
  { { "title", title },
  { "submitted-url", encodedUrl },
  {"description" , postdescription}
    }
};
```

Would an improperly formatted JSON object trip a 400 Bad Request Error?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. My Json string was messed up. "Post" and some {}'s were missing.

If anyone ends up reading this, also make sure your URL's are encoded. Test your json and example strings in the REST console here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console.

Some other tips, to save yourself some time - don't take any documentation/support posts or google'd solutions seriously if they're previous to 2013. There's some really bad/ugly stuff floating around that should just be deleted.